# Bash loop over files in directory outputting non existent files

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, directory, io

I am making mp4 files from a series of images. The images should run about 1 hour but I cannot get a full video because FFMPEG looks for a file it should not have.

```
[image2 @ 0x55fe14bef700] Could not open file : /mnt/run/image-005437.jpeg
```

What is confusing is that the list that I pass to ffmpeg *should* not include that file. If my script does not like the result it sends the file to a sub directory in the target folder called failed

the location of the file with that number

```
$ pwd
run/failed
]$ ls
failed-005437.jpeg
```

the command I use to launch ffmpeg is the following

```
image_folder=$1
singularity exec --bind $work_dir:/mnt $work_dir/longleaf2.sif ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -y -i <(for f in /mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/image-%06d.jpeg; do echo "file '$f'";done) -vf "crop=trunc(iw/3)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -movflags +faststart /mnt/run/summary_files/${image_folder}.mp4
```

I have checked processed images and it is not there so why is ffmpeg looking for it?

pastebin of the failed run

https://pastebin.com/pF5ZefLf

My check that the file is not in the folder reference by the for loop so that it should never cause an error

```
$ ls image-005437.*
ls: cannot access image-005437.*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

When you run:

```
for f in /mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/image-%06d.jpeg; do echo "file '$f'";done
```

It will output:

```
file '/mnt/processed_images/foo/image-%06d.jpeg'
```

So then ffmpeg will use the sequence pattern type for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). This expects a contiguous sequence.

## Solution 1: Glob

Use a glob:

```
for f in /mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/*.jpeg; do echo "file '$f'";done
```

Now it will output each file. In this example `image-000003.jpeg` does not exist so it does not get listed:

```
file '/mnt/processed_images/foo/image-000001.jpeg'
file '/mnt/processed_images/foo/image-000002.jpeg'
file '/mnt/processed_images/foo/image-000004.jpeg'
```

## Solution 2: Simplify and skip concat

Even better is to simplify your command by using the glob pattern type for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1) within ffmpeg itself, and then you can avoid the concat demuxer:

```
image_folder=$1
singularity exec --bind "$work_dir":/mnt "$work_dir"/longleaf2.sif ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -framerate 25 -i "/mnt/processed_images/$image_folder/*.jpeg" -vf "crop=trunc(iw/3)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2,format=yuv420p" -movflags +faststart /mnt/run/summary_files/${image_folder}.mp4
```

- The image demuxer glob pattern is not available for Windows users.
- Added the `-framerate` input option for the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1).
- Added the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format) to make YUV 4:2:0 chroma subsampling for compatibility.
- The variables have been quoted. See [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/).
- FFmpeg 4.1 release branch is old. [Download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or [compile](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) a modern version before doing anything else.

Comment: This worked beautifully many thanks!